# Find total lines of Python code excluding test cases

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, shell

We've got a Python application and want to count all the lines of code under a specific directory and its subdirectories.

We don't need to ignore comments but we want to ignore all files containing test cases.

Path to test cases file always has `/tests/` in the path `(e.g. /python/trieus/persistence/service/tests/batch_service_tests.py)`.

I used below command to find the count but it did not exclude test files.

```
find . -name "*.py" -not -path "./tests*" | xargs wc -l | sort
```

What's the correct syntax here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
find . -type d -name tests -prune -o -type f -name '*.py' \
       -exec grep -hxc '.*' {} + | paste -sd+ | bc
```

- `find . -type d -name tests -prune` excludes the `tests` directory
- `-type f -name '*.py'` matches only `.py` files
- `-exec grep -hxc '.*' {} +` get individual lines, you can modify the Regex pattern to meet you need here
- `paste -sd+` formats the output to put in a single line with `+` in between
- `bc` does the addition on its STDIN data

I would suggest you to go one step at a time to understand the whole thing better.

As a side note, this will not get you the actual LOC, instead would get you the lines count only.

Example from running in an example directory on my system:

```
% find . -type d -name tests -prune -o -type f -name '*.py' -exec grep -hxc '.*' {} + | paste -sd+ | bc
5594
```

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude a directory at ANY level by changing the first `.` to `*`. so `find -name "*.py" -not -path "*/tests/*"` would omit files from a directory named `"tests"` at any level of depth.

So the command will look like this:

`find . -name "*.py" -not -path "*/tests/*" | xargs wc -l | sort`

Comment: It says "find: expected an expression after '-o'"

Comment: Doesn't work. 1. It did not ignore files in  /tests/  2. it counted files other then .py as well

Comment: @LokeshAgrawal Updated, Please check